# Dashboard Lifetime sales and revenue is displaying different figure

Tags: magento-1.7, dashboard, revenue

I have a problem with dashboard, Lifetime Sales and Revenue displays different figure.i have tried displayed lifetime sales by following code:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('reports/order_collection')->calculateSales()->load()->getFirstItem()->getLifetime();
```

and it is displaying correct, same amount as Lifetime Sales on dashboard.

so i am getting confused whether lifetime sales is wrong or /revenue is wrong.

Can any body help me???

Comment: Just to check the easy stuff first, have you tried re-indexing the site? If so, how about going under "Reports" > Refresh Statistics and refreshing lifetime statistics for all of them?

Comment: I did it with:
Go to System → Config → Sales → Sale → Dashboard And mark
Use Aggregated Data (beta)="Yes"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it with: Go to System → Config → Sales → Sale → Dashboard And mark Use Aggregated Data (beta)="Yes"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but had to set Use Aggregated Data to ‘No’ to fix it.